# Distance $d$-independent set in hypercube

Tags: graph-theory, coding-theory

Given a graph $G = (V, E)$, a distance $d$-independent set is a subset $S \subseteq V$ such that any two vertices $x, y \in S$ have distance at least $d$.
Thus traditional independent sets are actually distance $2$-independent sets.
Denote by $\alpha_d(G)$ the maximum size of such a set in $G$.

I'm interested in $\alpha_d(Q_n)$, where $Q_n$ is the hypercube of dimension $n$ (i.e. $V(Q_n)$ is the set of all length $n$ binary strings, and two strings share an edge iff they differ by one bit).  We know about $\alpha_2(Q_n)$.  Is something known for larger $d$.

If not, is anything known specifically for $d = n/2$ ?  This is like asking how many strings can I find such that they are all have Hamming distance at least $n/2$.

Comment: If we define the Hamming graph $H(d,q)$ as the graph with vertex set $S_d$ (the set of all ordered $d$-tuples with entries from the $n$-element set $S= \lbrace 1,...,q \rbrace$) and edge set being the set of all pairs of vertices which differ in exactly one element, then hypercube $Q_n$ is $H(n,2)$ and the answer in https://mathoverflow.net/a/204046 may be relevant but might not be of much help for what you had in mind.